# Usage of "as to whether"

Tags: grammar

Can I ask you a question?

> People have varied perceptions as to whether parents should arrange the activities that children do in their free time.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?
Did the way I use the phrase "as to whether" sound natural to you?

Answer (score 3):

First, using "as to whether or not" instead of "as to whether" (as one contributor recommended) is an example of needless wordiness. It often sounds "better" to use more words, but such redundancy is an affectation and should be avoided. There is no difference in meaning between the two alternatives, and in standard written English it is better to avoid wordiness (see Strunk and White's *Elements of Style* or George Orwell's "Politics and the English Language" for the philosophy behind advocating economy of style).

The formulation "question(s) as to (+ embedded question)" can be used when the embedded clause is a yes/no question (in which case we would use "whether...") or an interrogative ("as to what/when/where...", etc.). Your formulation is correct and standard.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can I have another question? 
Is the word "perceptions" appropriate in this sentence? Should it be changed into "opinions". I am trying to sound more formal

Comment: I would use "perceptions" to refer to people's knowledge and attitude about something concrete (for instance, you might talk about people's "perceptions of the job market" or "perceptions of Europe"). If you're talking about people's attitudes toward a matter of opinion or a question for debate, then "opinions" or "beliefs" would be better. And "perception" isn't a more formal word than "opinion," though that's not a good reason to prefer it in any case.